# Permission code clarification needed

Tags: unix, file-permissions, chmod

I was reading some documentation where a developer is saying that a certain file needs to be set to **+rx mode** because the file is being accessed by outside services

What CHMOD code does this refer to? 777?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+rx` means: Add read and execute permissions (555) minus the umask bits to the default permissions.

Usually, the umask is 022 and the default permissions 644, so the result would be 755.

The calculation `0644 | (0555 & ~0022)`:

```
+rx                : 555 -> 101 101 101
Umask              : 022 -> 000 010 010 &~
                   ======================
Add these perms    : 555 -> 101 101 101
Default permissions: 644 -> 110 100 100 |
                   ======================
Result             : 755 -> 111 101 101
```

Comment: The umask is subtracted bitwise from the permissions, not XOR'd with them: `perm & ~umask`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `(0644 | 0555) & ~0022`

Comment: @Olayinka It should not be `(0644 | 0555) & ~0022`. "Default permissions" here refers to the current mode of a file. By adding `+rx` (which is affected by the umask), you get the calculation: `0644 | (0555 & ~0022)` (by symmetry of bitwise OR I swapped it to `(0555 & ~0022) | 0644` in the example).